# How should I implement verbose logging in an npm package?

Tags: node.js, logging, npm

I have created an npm package (for internal use) that can be used as follows. Note the `verboseLogging` option.

```
import * as q from 'q'

var client = q.createClient({verboseLogging: true})
```

I have implemented the `verboseLogging` as plenty of `console.log(...)` statements.

This works well when the consumer of the package is a NodeJS command line application, but not as well when the consumer of the package is a browser.

When I consume this package in a browser application, I have needed to do something like the following to get the logs displayed to the user:

```
const originalConsoleLog = console.log;

console.log = function() {
    // extract log message and save somewhere to be shown in DOM
    originalConsoleLog.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Is there maybe a better way to enable logging in an npm package that is accessible to both command line apps and browser apps?

Comment: what issue is it causing?

Comment: @vibhor1997a: The only issue is that I must monkey patch console.log

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to check if `window` variable id defined. Since it only presents in a browser, you can try something like this:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // we're server side, let console.log as is
} else {
    // browser environment, DOM is accessible, additional logging goes here
}
```